# Validate Phone Number Existence for United States

Tags: c#, validation

I wanna validate a given phone number for United States in C#. Is there any API or something for that which helps programmers to validate phone numbers **existence**. I don't wanna only validate if they're matching the format of phone numbers for USA but also their existence.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't all numbers in the US start with 555? That's my understand from all the Hollywood movies I've ever seen :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could validate phone number formats using a Regex such as those [listed here](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=6&categoryId=7), but in order to validate if the phone number really exists you would need to subscribe to a web service that holds current data for all phone numbers in the United States and publishes a method to validate such data. I don't think such a service would be free.

Also, take a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175488/us-phone-number-verification) on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've found something like this : [MelissaData.com](http://www.melissadata.com/dqt/xml.htm) They're offering a web service which verifies address,phone and name information.

Comment: The home page says: Phone Check:   (Coming Soon)

Comment: BTW, find out which phone numbers it will validate. Probably only numbers that are in the phone directory. Not _my_ number, for instance, which is a cell phone.

Comment: Well, actually you're right. I think it's not gonna be possible for me for a while.

Comment: And you are also right about land phone verification. They are not gonna provide cell numbers, I asked them.