# Javascript find a pattern in a string through regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have one string i want to check that wether that string has number or not , that string can contain the alphabets or mobile number with country code . So i want to detect that does it has mobile number ( which can have + or '0' and integers ) .

I tried using this [0-9] but i couldnt able to make the pattern for it .

thanks

Comment: You just need to try harder... I suggest you start here http://www.regular-expressions.info/ and really **learn** what regex are all about.

Comment: ok buddy i will try that link and get to know more about regex

Answer (score 0):

Is this string coming from a form input?  If so, there's a jQuery library for that called [Masked Input](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

If it's coming from a set variable that you want validated internally, you'll want to [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841888/validate-american-format-of-phone-number).

Hope this helps.

Comment: its coming from textbox . So it can be name of the contact and i have autocomplete in it , so if name come i pick the number from array ,and if no name there it should be integer having contactnumber so i want to check the pateren depending upon the text in textbox

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution

```
 \b[0-9+]+\b
```

Tested here

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html