# Regex to allow only digits, hypens, space, parentheses and should end with a digit (javascript)

Tags: regex, phone-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [US Phone Number Verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175488/us-phone-number-verification)

I need to validate US phone number.
It could be in the format:

```
xxx-xxx-xxxx
(xxx) xxx xxxx
(xxx)-xxx-xxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
```

but it should not be

```
xxx-xxx-xxxx-
-xxx-xxx-xxxx
```

It should accept digits, hyphens, space and parentheses.

Currently I use

```
^\[0-9 \-\. ]+$
```

which does not validate dash at the beginning or end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
^\(?\d{3}\)?[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}$
```

Comment: what you have this number : xxx)-xxx-xxx is it valid?

Comment: or this: `xxx) xxx-xxxx` or this: `xxxxxx xxxx`

Comment: i don't see why not. if the poster disagrees, i will be happy to edit my answer to rule such cases out, but as it is, the rx satisfies the requirements.

Comment: Thanks Staafi for the quick response. Unfortunately this code is throwing an error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression.

Comment: the regex was tested at http://regexpal.com/ and works correctly... please post a code snippet so i can see what the problem is

Comment: It works fine when I checked in online regex validator. But I use it with jquery validator. Code is like this.
Phone: { required: true, regex: "^\(?\d{3}\)?[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}$"},

Comment: you are missing the \ before the opening and closing parentheses in the beginning

Comment: I think it was stripped off when I copied. I tried exactly the same regex.

Comment: well, whatever the problem is, it's not in my submission, and i'm afraid i can't help you any further as it is

Comment: This solutions works. when I added it in a function and passed that function as jQuery validator rule it works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: this solution with some UI masking works perfect!

Answer (score 5):

Well my idea is (after some searching) not new at all! Look at this:

[A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

This is an Excellent suggestion btw.

Answer (score 2):

This one is probably correct (assuming some parsing errors depending on the regex engine you are using. It's also ugly as hell :(.

```
(?:\d{3}(?:\d{7}|\-\d{3}\-\d{4}))|(?:\(\d{3}\)(?:\-\d{3}\-)|(?: \d{3} )\d{4})
```

Comment: I will not even try to understand this :) +1 for the work, still.

Comment: it's basically trying first `xxxxxxxxxx` and then `xxx-xxx-xxxx` and if that fails it will try `(xxx)-xxx-xxxx` and then `(xxx) xxx xxxx`. But the escaping and parenthesis mess it up.

Comment: aha! great idea, validation through exclusion. I wonder if this common problem has a 'universal' library solver.

Answer (score 2):

```
(^\(?[0-9]{3}\)?\-?\s?[0-9]{3}\-?\s?[0-9]{4}[^-])
```

I tested this on http://regexhero.net/tester/ and got it to select the following patterns:

```
xxx-xxx-xxxx 
(xxx) xxx xxxx 
(xxx)-xxx-xxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
```

It ignored the following patterns:

```
xxx-xxx-xxxx- 
-xxx-xxx-xxxx
```

I hope this helps, or at least moves you in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
/^([\d]{6}|((\([\d]{3}\)|[\d]{3})( [\d]{3} |-[\d]{3}-)))[\d]{4}$/
```

- It starts by checking if the first 6 digits are `xxxxxx`,
- if not it looks if the first three digits are `(xxx)` or just `xxx`

  - and if one of those it checks if the next three are `xxx` or `-xxx-`
- At the end it checks that there are four trailing digits `xxxx`