# Regular expression to match Phone Number pattern of USA in java

Tags: javascript, regex, phone-number

Can somebody give me the regex for phone number.

**The format is :**

A phone number used for calls must contain only the characters  `+` , `–` , `*` and `0-9`.

Only the leading character may be a  `+`  **Or**  `*`

Comment: I am completely new to this feature hence not sure abt what the expression should be. Basically the length od the phone number should not be more that 30 chararters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex will do:

```
^\+?[0-9\-]+\*?$
```

How it works:

2. Beginning of string: `^`
3. Optional + character, escaped because "+" could also be a regex operator: `\+?`
4. At least one character which is either 0-9 or "-", escaped because "-" could also be a regex operator: `[0-9\-]+`
5. Optional "*" character, escaped: `\*?`
6. End of string: `$'

Note that this is just a simple example to match the pattern as you defined it. A more elaborate discussion on handling US phone numbers with Regex can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175488/us-phone-number-verification)

Comment: @onon15 no need to escape the `-` since it's at the end of the class (at the beginning would have been the same by the way).